# Magento 2.1 - How to resolve PHP Fatal error: Class 'Zend_Captcha_Image' not found issue?

Tags: magento-2.1, zend-framework

I'm using Magento 2.1.I just updated my composer and after that When I run setup:upgrade it's showing me error

```
PHP Fatal error: Class 'Zend_Captcha_Image' not found in vendor/magento/module-captcha/Model/DefaultModel.php on line 13
```

How can I resolve this issue?

any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Was that you trying to upgrade your Magento using composer? You may forgot to put your store in maintenance mode and backup data

Comment: what is the solution for this?